# pydev plugin in eclipse not showing the files in the project explorer

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I am using pydev plugin in eclipse. I can create the project, but I cannot see the files in the project explorer.

I am attaching the screenshot. Any idea how to fix it.

Thanks
Kiran

[image]

Answer (score 3):

in Pydev explorer Ctrl+F10 then from Top Level Elements choose Projects. It will show the projects in your workspace

Answer (score 2):

I got a little workaround. I'm not sure what the difference between "PyDev Package Explorer" and "Package Explorer" is supposed to be, but it's clear that one of them is buggy.

I'm well aware that this is from 2011, but I came across this question while searching for it. I hope my answer will help someone.

1. Ensure you are in the "PyDev" perspective.
2. Top menu bar > Window > Customize Perspective...
3. Menu Visibility tab
4. Under "Edit", tick the "Show views" box (it might be half-ticked somehow depending on how your OS displays that). Press OK.
5. Top menu bar > Window > Show view > Package Explorer
6. A new 'view' should now be visible, called "Package Explorer". Move Package Explorer to an appropriate space (click and drag).
7. Delete the old "PyDev Package Explorer".

Comment: Thanks for this! It's almost a year later and it still worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04, Eclipse Luna. My problem was a little different - I could create projects, but they weren't showing up at all.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Eclipse does not have the resources up to date...

Have you configured Eclipse to do automatic refresh of resources?

1. Preferences > General > Startup and Shutdown: check 'Refresh workspace on startup'
2. Preferences > Workspace: check: Refresh automatically (this depends on your Eclipse version -- in 3.7 the settings were changed a bit, but it should be easy to know which configurations are related).

You can also try making a manual refresh: either F5 or right-click: refresh.

Another thing to check is if the path of the project is actually the path you're expecting (i.e.: the path that has the resources) -- you can press Alt+Enter to open the properties  for the project and check if the location is actually correct.